# What are the differences between roaming free in the early chapters and after epilogue chapter 2?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

Be warned, this question contains serious end game spoilers. Don't read it unless you finished the game.

> I just finished the second epilogue chapter, and I'm wondering now if I should finish the remaining open world stuff in the epilogue with John instead of Arthur, with an earlier save or a new game. So I'm mostly wondering if there are side missions that are not available after the epilogue, or any other differences compared to the early game. Is there any content that is exclusively available before or after the epilogue?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer Summary**

> To answer your question, There are missions that are available in some
>  chapters (While playing as Arthur) that aren't after/during the
>  epilogue (While playing as John). Here is a list of missable missions
>  (that must be played as Arthur) with their corresponding chapters:

(found at: https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/450689-red-dead-redemption-2-missable-missions-quests-point-of-no-return)

**RED DEAD REDEMPTION 2 MISSABLE MISSIONS OR QUESTS (CHAPTER 2):**

- Good, Honest Snake Oil (Valentine Police Station. To be completed by Chapter 6)

**RED DEAD REDEMPTION 2 MISSABLE MISSIONS OR QUESTS (CHAPTER 4):**

- Brothers and Sisters, One and All (Available after completing “Help a Brother Out”; head to the church north of Saint Denis. To be completed by Chapter 4)
- Fatherhood and Other Dreams (Available after completing “Angelo Bronto, A Man of Honor”; head to Arthur’s room and read the letter. To be completed by Chapter 4)

**RED DEAD REDEMPTION 2 MISSABLE MISSIONS OR QUESTS (CHAPTER 6):**

- Do Not Seek Absolution I and II (Available with a honor rank of at least 4 from the coal mine in Annensburg. To be completed by Chapter 6)
- Of Men and Angels I and II (Available from the church in Saint Denis. To be completed by Chapter 6.)
- The Course of True Love IV and V (Read the letter from Penelope in your tent after completing a mission following Chapter 5. To be completed by Chapter 6.)
- Money Lending and Other Sins VI and VII (Speak to Strauss in the camp. To be completed by Chapter 6.)